# Is it possible to use functools.singledispatch with composite/nested/container types in Python?

Tags: python, typing, functools, multimethod, multiple-dispatch

Edit 2022-08-30: perhaps with the introduction of variadic generics ([PEP-646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/)) in Python 3.11, dispatch with composite types may become possible.

I wonder whether the following can be achieved,
and if so, without requiring much extra code:

```python
from __future__ import annotations
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def somefunc(value):
    print(f"Type {type(value).__qualname__!r} "
          f"is not registered for dispatch.")

@somefunc.register
def _(value: list[int]):
    print(f"Dispatched type list[int]!")

@somefunc.register
def _(value: list[str]):
    print(f"Dispatched type list[str]!")

somefunc('123')
somefunc([123])
somefunc(list('123'))
```

And get output:

```
Type 'str' is not registered for dispatch.
Dispatched type list[int]!
Dispatched type list[str]!
```

Running this snippet with python 3.9.6, however, instead results in an error at line 742 of functools.py:

```
TypeError: issubclass() argument 2 cannot be 
a parameterized generic
```

As `singledispatch` does work for user defined classes, one way to make this work is to typecheck the elements in the passed list, wrap the passed list into a class representing e.g. `list[str]` and have the dispatched function call itself again with the new instance as argument:

```python
from __future__ import annotations
from functools import singledispatch


class ListOfStrs(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class ListOfInts(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


@singledispatch
def somefunc(value):
    print(f"Type {type(value).__qualname__!r} "
          f"is not registered for dispatch.")


@somefunc.register
def _(value: list):
    if value and all(isinstance(subval, int) 
                     for subval in value):
        somefunc(ListOfInts(value))

    elif value and all(isinstance(subval, str) 
                       for subval in value):
        somefunc(ListOfStrs(value))

    else:
        print(
            f"Dispatched a list whose elements ",
            f"are not all of a registered type."
            )


@somefunc.register
def _(value: ListOfStrs):
    print(f"Dispatched type 'list[str]'!")


@somefunc.register
def _(value: ListOfInts):
    print(f"Dispatched type 'list[int]'!")


somefunc('123')
somefunc([1, 2, 3])
somefunc(list('123'))
somefunc([{1}, {2}, {3}])
```

Which, as expected, results in:

```
Type 'str' is not registered for dispatch.
Dispatched type 'list[int]'!
Dispatched type 'list[str]'!
Dispatched a list whose elements are 
 not all of a registered type.
```

However, besides increasing extensibility, one of the reasons to use `singledispatch` in the first place is to circumvent verbose typechecks, which some consider an anti-pattern. And of course for this solution specifically, you'd need to define the wrapper classes which litter the code (there may be a better way of achieving  this that I currently don't see, but the first point still stands).

One could reason one typecheck for 'list' is avoided here, but that reduces complexity just by just one if/else clause.

So I wouldn't actually use the last case.

Does anyone know how to get this behaviour as elegantly as can be done with non-composite types?

I suppose this could be done elegantly using pattern matching in 3.10. So maybe I should wait for its launch and maturation if this is currently not feasible?

Comment: No, because fundamentally `list[int]` is not a "real," type.

Comment: Could you expand on that? Why would that prevent such an implementation for `singledispatch`, compared to how static typecheckers infer composite types? `singledispatch` seems to make use of the annotations, so why couldn't it be implemented to infer nested types in a similar fashion?

Comment: Because statics type checkers use static analysis, which is absolutely not what the single dispatch decorator is doing. It is essentially using a runtime `isinstance` check. Python is fundamentally a dynamically typed language, and container types are never restricted at runtime

Comment: Ah right, thanks. I guess an implementation is possible using something like the second example in the question internally, but this could result in significant overhead for large containers and it may also not be clear immediately that it only works if all container elements are of the same type.

Comment: yes, I highly suggest *never* doing anything like that and instead just use `mypy`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't understand how `mypy` is relevant here. I'm not using it for static type analysis. I'd like dispatch to be compatible w/ a subset of container instances. E.g. only homogeneous containers with max 1 level of nesting. Whether that is a bad idea / reduces maintainability/readability is a separate point though and I suppose context-dependent.

Comment: No, I'm saying you shouldn't add runtime checks that verify a list is of homogenous type, i.e. `all(isinstance(x, str) for x in mylist)`, this adds absurd linear time check for simply passing a list this function. Instead, you *should use mypy in lieu of this*. And note, I don't think pattern matching would help you here.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. Agreed. Thanks again.
For the use case I had in mind the performance hit would be negligible though.